# duplicate options showing when trying to search in database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using php, and trying to build a code that allows me to search through my sql database vendors' passwords 
The search is based on vendor name . And it is possible that one vendor has more than one password .
it is working fine , but one problem , which is when I try to select the vendor name , it is showing more than one time if in the database it shows more than one time .
So how can I manage not to display the vendor name more than one time in the search options ?
This is the php code I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<form action="/cloudpass/searchvendors.php" id="searchv" "method="GET"><br/><br/>
<select name="query" form="searchv">
<?php

$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'mysql')
or die ('Cannot connect to db');

$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT vendor_name FROM vendors");

while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){

$vendor_name = $row['vendor_name'];
echo '<option value="'.$vendor_name.'">'. $row['vendor_name'] .'</option>';
}
?>
</select>

        <input type="submit" value="search" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

[And this is my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bM9W.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for avoid duplicated  value  simply use distinct  clause

```
 SELECT distinct vendor_name FROM vendors
```